# Как получить значение name из input [php]

Tags: php, html

`'<form method="post" action="vendor/delete-post.php">'.`
`'<button class="btn-delete-post" name="'.$rows['id'].'">Удалить</button>'.`
`'</form>'.`
У меня есть кнопка, которой в name присваивается айди поста при создании, по нажатию я перехожу в delete-post.php где нужно удалить пост с айди как у кнопки, для этого мне нужно получить значение name из input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$rows['id'].'">
<button class="btn-delete-post" type="submit" >Удалить</button>
```

В скрипте vendor/delete-post.php :
`$_POST["ID"]` и будет иметь ваше значение